# Change seed method for an existing Asp.Net MVC 5 (Identity 2) application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

How to add a fixed role (e.g. Admin) to an existing Asp.Net Mvc/Identity 2 site?

In the link
http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/, there are the following code which is exactly what I want to do. However, will the `Seed` function be executed since the application? (I already have some code, `var lookup1 = new List<L1>{new L1 {...},...}; tableL1.ForEach(l => context.tableL1.AddOrUpdate(p=>p.Title, l)); context.SaveChanges();`, in the `Seed` function to seed some lookup tables.). What's the right way to Add a role to an application which is already online?

```
// internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(AspNetIdentity.WebApi.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "SuperPowerUser",
            Email = "taiseer.joudeh@gmail.com",
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            FirstName = "Taiseer",
            LastName = "Joudeh",
            Level = 1,
            JoinDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3)
        };

        manager.Create(user, "MySuperP@ss!");

        if (roleManager.Roles.Count() == 0)
        {
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "SuperAdmin" });
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin"});
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "User"});
        }

        var adminUser = manager.FindByName("SuperPowerUser");

        manager.AddToRoles(adminUser.Id, new string[] { "SuperAdmin", "Admin" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? Cheers.

Comment: No, still no solution. I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869823/insert-data-in-asp-net-identity-tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to seed the database you have to `Enable-Migrations` in the **Package Manager Console**.

I guess you have done that already since you already have the **Configuration.cs** file.

In the constructor of you `configuration` class make sure `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` is set to `false` or your database will be recreated.

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
}
```

Now you can compile your solution and from **Package Manager Console** (Make sure your selecting the right project in the Default Project combo) run:

```
Update-Database
```

or

```
Update-Database -Verbose
```

if you want to collect more info.

and you should see your new data in the database.

Comment: Will the `Update-Database` only update the local DB? I guess I will need to generate the SQL script and run it on the server.

Comment: It would use the string connection defined in your web.config, the one you're using for the EF stuff.